# Jquery modify elements in each loop

Tags: jquery, loops, each, selector

Using jquery, I want to loop all elements having the class "item" and apply different background colors according to the index of the element.

mapcolor is an array of colors (length = number of elements having "item" class)

```
$.each($(".item"), function(i,e){
$("#"+e).css("background-color",mapcolor[i]);
});
```

`$("#"+e)` selector doesn't work as expected, neither `$("#"+e.id)` ... 
Something's wrong with my selector. Any idea?

Comment: Try `$(this).css("background-color",mapcolor[i]);`. I think this will work if not please let me know about your HTML DOM structure.

Comment: better to use `$(selector).each()` method instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help.Actually every span is colored with the same color in my programm and it doesn't work. The issue must be elsewhere... I'm trying to figure out where.

Comment: Ok i figured out where was the issue. It was in another part of my programm and not in that "each loop". Thank you guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `.each()` method instead and you have to be in the context with `$(this)`:

```
$(".item").each(function(i){
  $(this).css("background-color",mapcolor[i]);
});
```

Yet a better way is:

```
$(".item").css("background-color",function(){
    return mapcolor[$(this).index()];
});
```

make use of `.css()` method and pass a callback function to return the value.

A test is below:

```js
var mapcolor = ['green', 'red', 'yellow'];

$(".item").css("background", function() {
  return mapcolor[$(this).index()];
});
```

```css
div{height:10px;}
```

```html
<div class='item'></div>
<div class='item'></div>
<div class='item'></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've already tried that. Doesn't work.. It applies the same color (last one) to all elements

Comment: @Abspirit check a test snipped i have added.

Comment: @Abspirit the code snippet you have thrown here that led us to answer this so you have to ensure that this line is not in any other loop.

Answer (score 3):

yes problem is in your selector ... 
problem is on this like

```
$("#"+e).css("background-color",mapcolor[i]);
```

why you using # with e because # represent id ..
but here e is representing current selected tag in loop

so simply use $(e).css("background-color",mapcolor[i]); in your way..

or short and better way use this

```
$(".item").each(function(i){
    $(this).css("background-color",mapcolor[i]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$( ".item" ).each(function(i) {
  $(this).css("background-color",mapcolor[i]);
});
```

Comment: I've already tried that. Doesn't work.. It applies the same color (last one) to all elements

Comment: Can you please provide your HTML structure. So that I can see the exact issue.

Comment: If possible add to a `jsfiddle`. It's easier to see the exact issue.