# How to only use a single instance of multiple same name classes

Tags: jquery, django

When clicking on a link, it changes from like to unlike or vice versa but, the number of likes and unlikes are supposed to change uniquely and not every single one of the posts in the same page. A for loop in Django is used to call the posts, so that they have the same class names. The jQuery below is supposed to change the like count of a specific post, but it changes every single one due to the class name. How can this be done please?

**jquery extract**

```
 var previous_likes = parseInt($('span.count .total').text());
 $('span.count .total').text(previous_action == 'like' ? previous_likes + 1 : previous_likes - 1);
```

**full jquery code**

```
$('a.like').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();

    $.post('{% url "posts:post_like" %}',
      {
        id: $(this).data('id'),
        action: $(this).data('action')
      },
      function(data){
        if (data['status'] == 'ok')
        {
          var previous_action = $(event.target).data('action');

          // toggle data-action
          $(event.target).data('action', previous_action == 'like' ?
          'unlike' : 'like');
          // toggle link text
          $(event.target).text(previous_action == 'like' ? 'Unlike' :
          'Like');

          // update total likes

          var previous_likes = parseInt($('span.count .total').text());
          $('span.count .total').text(previous_action == 'like' ? previous_likes + 1 : previous_likes - 1);
        }
      }
    );
  });
```

**HTML**

```
 {% for post in posts %}
       <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url}}" class="text-dark">
            <div class="d-flex bg-white pt-3 pl-2">
                    
    
                <div class=" p-2 mb-2">
                   {% with total_likes=post.users_like.count users_like=post.users_like.all %}
                            
                   <span class="count">
                       <span class="total">{{ total_likes }}</span> like{{ total_likes|pluralize }}
                            
                    </span>

                        
                    <p>
                        <span class="mr-5 ">
                            <a href="" data-id="{{ post.id }}" 
                                    data-action="{% if request.user in users_like %}un{% endif %}like" 
                                    class="like">

                                {% if request.user not in users_like %}
                                    Like
                                {% else %}
                                   Unlike
                                {% endif %}
                            </a>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    {% endwith %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: show your html structure

Comment: ok I've edited the post

Comment: I think you can do this using each or eq.  Here's how to do it using each: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32092973/jquery-modify-elements-in-each-loop  Or, maybe using find?

Comment: Try like : `var previous_likes = parseInt($(event.target).closest("div").find("span.count .total").text()); $(event.target).closest("div").find("span.count .total").text(previous_action == 'like' ? previous_likes + 1 : previous_likes - 1);`